# R expression can't be shown Mac book

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, axis-labels

I am trying to plot a graph with the following expression in the x or y label:
e.g.

```
qplot(x=rnorm(20), y=rnorm(20))+ 
  ylab("Per mil--> [\u2030]")+ #this works for me
  xlab(expression(paste(delta,""^"13","C [\u2030]"))) #this doesn't work on my Mac and shows: d13C [ U+2030>], where d13C is correctly shown, but the sign for per mil not; on Windows this expression was working
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
qplot(x=rnorm(20), y=rnorm(20)) + 
  ylab("Per mil--> [\u2030]") + 
  xlab("\u03B4\u00B9\u00B3C [\u2030]")
```

[image]

Comment: ...BUT for delta^18 O iit doesn't work for the superscript 8: xlab("\u03B4\u00B9\u2078O [\u2030]") --> only a square is depicted for this character

Comment: @SaRa And presumably `xlab(expression(delta^{18}*"O [\u2030]"))` doesn't work on the Mac?

Comment: @SaRa What displays incorrectly? The per mil symbol? If so, does this work `xlab(expression(delta^{18}*"O [‰]"))`?

Comment: With: xlab(expression(delta^{18}*"O [\u2030]")) only the per mil sign can't depicted, d18O is fine

With: xlab(expression(delta^{18}*"O [‰]")) also d18O is fine, but then it shows [...]

With a windows system, I could depict all of the above options, but I have to use a Mac (I am a newbie concerning Macs) now... Is there some sort of extra package for Macs or for characters in Mac etc.?
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @SaRa Or even `xlab(quote(delta^{18}*"O [\u2030]"))`?

Comment: Hmm, both are also not working. Same as above. BTW, there is no error or warning message, it just doesn't want to show the symbol.

Comment: @SaRa Cludgy, but what about this? `xlab(expression(delta^{18}*"O [\u00B0/"["\u00BA\u00BA"]*"]"))` or `xlab(expression(delta^{18}*"O ["^{0}*"/"["00"]*"]"))`

Comment: Thank you for experimenting on this!!! The last one (xlab(expression(delta^{18}*"O ["^{0}*"/"["00"]*"]"))) worked out :) Yeah!

Comment: No worries. Sorry I don't have a more elegant solution!

Comment: This is a good alternative! FYI: I replaced zero with the small letter o for the per mil sign, that looks a bit better.